# How to set the image of one UIimageView as background of other UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uikit

How to set the image of one UIimageView as background of other UIImageView?

I am using 2 viewcontrollers. In 1st view, I am using an imageview & I want this image as background of other imageView of 2 viewcontroller

Comment: Let's start with definition of "background of another *view*".

Comment: I think its background of background of foreground of another image view.

Comment: you can directly set whatever image you want to the second imageView...what is this background of imageView ?

Comment: I think I got him....he wants to put a first image view below the second imageview in secondView controller, which we can simply do by addSubView method....am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

If the two controllers are connected via a segue you can expose the ImageView in the header of the second controller and set that in the "prepareForSegue" method like that:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *upcoming = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"]) {
        upcoming.imageView.image = self.imageView.image;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm using Xib not storyboard

Comment: Do you call the second ViewController from the first? If yes, can you post the code of the calling? Thank you.